# Named stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to call the stored procedure based on named parameters.

```
RMFF_RETRO_ACTIVE_CALCS_SP(p_region_cd,p_plant_cd,
p_supplier_nbr,p_matrl_nbr,'','','N',p_user_id,p_err_cd,p_err_msg);
```

In this I need to use named parameter.

but my `p_region_cd` has the same name as that of called procedure

```
p_region_cd=>p_region_cd.
```

How to do this? I need a named only in 5,6 th place

Pls suggest me how to call

Comment: well, you cant use named parameters in "the middle" and then go back using normal parameter list. I suggest use named parameters throughout...

Comment: The fact that your local param has the same name as procedure param shouldn't be a problem. But still you have to name all parameters in your call.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
p_region_cd=>p_region_cd
```

should not be a problem. For example following block runs just fine.

```
declare 
  po_next_stmt_date number(8);
  po_next_due_date  number(8);
  po_rsp_code       varchar2(3);
  po_rsp_dscr       varchar2(256);

begin
  oc_eoc.SP_EOC_GET_NEXT_STMT_DATE(pi_last_eoc_date => 20130210,
                                   pi_new_cycle_code => '02',
                                   po_next_stmt_date => po_next_stmt_date,
                                   po_next_due_date => po_next_due_date,
                                   po_rsp_code => po_rsp_code,
                                   po_rsp_dscr => po_rsp_dscr);
end;
```

The thing you have to take care is that if you start with named parameters then you have to go on with that. The following is also fine:

```
oc_eoc.SP_EOC_GET_NEXT_STMT_DATE(20130210,
                                 '02',
                                 po_next_stmt_date => po_next_stmt_date,
                                 po_next_due_date => po_next_due_date,
                                 po_rsp_code => po_rsp_code,
                                 po_rsp_dscr => po_rsp_dscr);
```

but this is not:

```
oc_eoc.SP_EOC_GET_NEXT_STMT_DATE(pi_last_eoc_date => 20130210,
                                 '02',
                                 po_next_stmt_date => po_next_stmt_date,
                                 po_next_due_date => po_next_due_date,
                                 po_rsp_code => po_rsp_code,
                                 po_rsp_dscr => po_rsp_dscr);
```